# Only use a where clause when bit = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some SQL code that looks like this at the moment.

```
    insert into @SortedProducts (peid)
    select pd.ProductEntryId 
    from @ProductFilters FILT
        INNER JOIN J_ProductDetails pd ON FILT.ProductEntryId = pd.ProductEntryId
    WHERE pd.Active = 'True'
    and pd.IsRangeOfProducts = CASE WHEN @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 1 then 0 else 1 END
```

However, on the last line, I only want to apply that where clause if @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 1

If @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 0 then I should not have this where clause. pd.IsRangeOfProducts is also a bit.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: WHERE @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 1 and pd.Active = 'True' and pd.IsRangeOfProducts = 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use boolean logic:

```
insert into @SortedProducts (peid)
    select pd.ProductEntryId 
    from @ProductFilters FILT join
         J_ProductDetails pd 
         on FILT.ProductEntryId = pd.ProductEntryId
    where pd.Active = 'True' and
          (@ClearanceFeatureApplied <> 1  or pd.IsRangeOfProducts = 0) ;
```

Comment: This is a better answer, but I think it should be `(@ClearanceFeatureApplied <> 1  or pd.IsRangeOfProducts = 0)` - if @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 1, then you only want pd.IsRangeOfProducts = ~@ClearanceFeatureApplied

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add an OR to the where clause (surrounded by brackets) to ignore this section when @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 0:

```
insert into @SortedProducts (peid)
select pd.ProductEntryId 
from @ProductFilters FILT
    INNER JOIN J_ProductDetails pd ON FILT.ProductEntryId = pd.ProductEntryId
WHERE pd.Active = 'True'
and (@ClearanceFeatureApplied = 0 OR pd.IsRangeOfProducts = CASE WHEN @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 1 then 0 else 1 END)
```

If you have nulls in your bit columns, you will need to componsate for that.

Comment: Don't you feel where condition look weird?

Comment: This Query can't make condition "pd.Active = 'True' " ignore when @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 0

Comment: That's why there are brackets. This means it will be resolved first, before the pd.Active is checked.

Comment: You could simplify like this: `WHERE pd.Active = 'True' and (@ClearanceFeatureApplied = 0 OR pd.IsRangeOfProducts = ~@ClearanceFeatureApplied)`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood this correctly, then maybe something like:

```
WHERE pd.Active = 'True'
    and 1 = CASE WHEN @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 0 THEN 1 
                 WHEN pd.IsRangeOfProducts = 0 THEN 1  -- XX
                 ELSE 0 END
```

Above assumes @ClearanceFeatureApplied will not be null. 
If you get to line XX, then @ClearanceFeatureApplied will always be 1, 
so I optimized the condition:

```
 and pd.IsRangeOfProducts = CASE WHEN @ClearanceFeatureApplied = 1 then 0 else 1 END
```

to:

```
  pd.IsRangeOfProducts = 0
```